# Scala flattening loses the desired grouping of the subsets by size

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Count of the number of sum of the cubes equal to the target value.

For a small number of sets this code works (`target` is `100` vs `1000`). When the target value increases the system runs out of resources. I have not flattened `allsets` with the intention of only creating & processing the smaller subsets as needed.

How do I lazily create/use the subsets by size until the sums for all the `Sets` of one size equal or exceed the target, at which point nothing more needs to be examined because the rest of the sums will be larger than the target.

```
val target = 100; val exp = 3; val maxi = math.pow(target, 1.0/exp).toInt;
target: Int = 100
exp: Int = 3
maxi: Int = 4

val allterms=(1 to maxi).map(math.pow(_,exp).toInt).to[Set];
allterms: Set[Int] = Set(1, 8, 27, 64)

val allsets = (1 to maxi).map(allterms.subsets(_).to[Vector]); allsets.mkString("\n");
allsets: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]]] = Vector(Vector(Set(1), Set(8), Set(27), Set(64)), Vector(Set(1, 8), Set(1, 27), Set(1, 64), Set(8, 27), Set(8, 64), Set(27, 64)), Vector(Set(1, 8, 27), Set(1, 8, 64), Set(1, 27, 64), Set(8, 27, 64)), Vector(Set(1, 8, 27, 64)))
res7: String =
Vector(Set(1), Set(8), Set(27), Set(64))
Vector(Set(1, 8), Set(1, 27), Set(1, 64), Set(8, 27), Set(8, 64), Set(27, 64))
Vector(Set(1, 8, 27), Set(1, 8, 64), Set(1, 27, 64), Set(8, 27, 64))
Vector(Set(1, 8, 27, 64))

allsets.flatten.map(_.sum).filter(_==target).size;
res8: Int = 1
```

This implementation loses the separation of the subsets by size.

Comment: @MarioGalic http://julianlocals.com/cwhii/2019/so/56876326_scala-flattening-loses-the-desired-grouping-of-the-subsets-by-size.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add laziness to your calculations in two ways:

1. Use `combinations()` instead of `subsets()`. This creates an `Iterator` so the combination (collection of `Int` values) won't be realized until it is needed.
2. Use a `Stream` (or `LazyList` if Scala 2.13.0) so that each "row" (same sized combinations) won't be realized until it is needed.

Then you can trim the number of rows to be realized by using the fact that the first combination of each row is going to have the minimum `sum` of that row.

```scala
val target = 125
val exp = 2
val maxi = math.pow(target, 1.0/exp).toInt  //maxi: Int = 11

val allterms=(1 to maxi).map(math.pow(_,exp).toInt)
//allterms = Seq(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121)

val allsets = Stream.range(1,maxi+1).map(allterms.combinations)
//allsets: Stream[Iterator[IndexedSeq[Int]]] = Stream(<iterator>, ?)
//  11 rows, 2047 combinations, all unrealized

allsets.map(_.map(_.sum).buffered)   //Stream[BufferedIterator[Int]]
       .takeWhile(_.head <= target)  // 6 rows
       .flatten                      // 1479 combinations
       .count(_ == target)
//res0: Int = 5
```

Comment: When I try it on a smaller value so I can see everything, val target = 10; It looks to me like the heads are missing from the sums that are included inn the count:
allsets.takeWhile(_.buffered.head.sum<=target).flatten.mkString(" ") // Vector(4) Vector(9) Vector(1, 9) Vector(4, 9)

Comment: @CWHolemanII; You're right. The `sum <= target` comparison was consuming that iterator. Corrected.